# check many req.body values (nodejs API)

Tags: node.js

Is there a good, efficient way to check many req.body values whether they are not undefined or null?

At most I have about 17 values to check.

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe that checking each one of them is very slow ?

Comment: You can use joi validator. Which I'm using for body validation. Here's the link you can take a look. https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @alfasin it just looks very unreadable haha

Comment: You should do it in another validation function and call it from your code - it will make your code much more readable. See @jfriend00 answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that takes a list of property names and checks to see if they have values other than `null` or `undefined`.

```
// checks to see if all props in the list are available and non-null
// list can either be an array or a | separated string
function checkProps(obj, list) {
    if (typeof list === "string") {
        list = list.split("|");
    }
    for (prop of list) {
        let val = obj[prop];
        if (val === null || val === undefined) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then, you could use it like this:

```
if (!checkProps(req.body, "email|firstName|lastName|address1|city|state|zip")) {
    // some properties missing
} else {
    // all properties available
}
```

Comment: will check this later, working on a different project for now.

Comment: @Rachelle - Did this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and also earn yourself some reputation points for following the proper procedure here on stack overflow.  It isn't really appropriate to post a question and then just announce that you won't be paying any attention to the answers because you're now doing something else.  That's not how things work here.

Comment: sorry, it's just that I had other deadlines hammering on my desk! just tried it and works very well and clean! thanks for your help.

Comment: @Rachelle - OK, glad you got some time for it now, but if you want people to help you here and you want to be a good citizen here, then you should really only post here when you will have some time to pay attention to the responses.  Often times people will need to engage you with questions and if you're not ready to be responsive, then the whole model here breaks down - it gets frustrating and inefficient for people trying to help, questions lie fallow as unclear with no answers, etc...  That's why the model here is you post and you engage.  If you can't engage, wait until you have time to.